# ServiceStack error calling Request.GetRawBody();

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicestack

I am attempting to get access to the underlying JSON object (request body) within a service call in service stack.  The reason I wish to do this is to create a PATCH version of an existing service, which will only attempt to update fields that were in the JSON.  Seems simple enough:

```
    public object Patch(AddUpdateContactRequest request)
    {
        var json = this.Request.GetRawBody();
        var keysToUpdate = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);

        return Put(request);
    }
```

However, I get an exception from service stack when GetRawBody() is called (when service stack is calling in to .NET core):

> Message: "Could not load type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper' from assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'."
>       Source: "ServiceStack"
>       StackTrace: "   at ServiceStack.Host.NetCore.NetCoreRequest.GetRawBody() in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\NetCore\NetCoreRequest.cs:line
>   211"
>       TargetSite: {System.String GetRawBody()}
>       TypeName: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper"

It seems to be referencing version 3.0 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, but this version does not have the namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper.  It looks like a version mismatch issue, but I cannot seem to make it work.  I cannot see any dll version conflicts locally, I am implicitly referencing the latest version of .NET core and have the latest SDK/hosting package installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is .NET Core 3.0 this is [due to a breaking change in .NET Core 3.0](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/netcore-3-0-getrawbody-could-not-load-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-internal-bufferinghelper/7883/2?u=mythz) which has been resolved in the [latest v5.7.1 packages on MyGet](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: That was it and that is solved - thanks so much for the response and saving a headache.  Do you happen to know when 5.7.1 will go live, or can this release be treated as live?

Comment: @DavidHiblen you can treat it as live - the pre-release packages go through the same CI + test suite as NuGet releases which are just an immutable snapshot in time of the same packages.